# Set segment duration with media convert

Tags: amazon-web-services, mpeg-dash, aws-media-convert

With AWS media convert everytime I convert an mp4 (6 second video) to a dash, the segment duration is about 30 seconds however I'd much appreciate if it were 1 second or less:

```
      <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" duration="324000" startNumber="1"/>
      <Representation id="1" width="1280" height="720" bandwidth="72000000" codecs="avc1.4d4032">
        <SegmentTemplate media="5f8283b60a3ac3640191892_$Number%09d$.mp4" initialization="5f8283b60a3ac3640191892init.mp4" duration="324000" startNumber="1"/>
      </Representation>
      <Representation id="2" width="1920" height="1080" bandwidth="16200000" codecs="avc1.4d4029">
        <SegmentTemplate media="5f8283b60a3ac3640191891_$Number%09d$.mp4" initialization="5f8283b60a3ac3640191891init.mp4" duration="324000" startNumber="1"/>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
```

I've tried messing with the job settings, but nothing I did seemed to work. Sometimes I got it down to 10 seconds, but that still isn't great, anyway here are the settings I used:

```
$jobSetting = [
      "OutputGroups"=> [
      [
        "CustomName"=> "nicenice",
        "Name"=> "DASH ISO",
        "Outputs"=> [
          [
            "ContainerSettings"=> [
              "Container"=> "MPD"
            ],
            "VideoDescription"=> [
              "Width"=> 1920,
              "ScalingBehavior"=> "DEFAULT",
              "Height"=> 1080,
              "TimecodeInsertion"=> "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias"=> "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness"=> 50,
              "CodecSettings"=> [
                "Codec"=> "H_264",
                "H264Settings"=> [
                  "InterlaceMode"=> "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames"=> 3,
                  "Syntax"=> "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness"=> 0,
                  "GopClosedCadence"=> 1,
                  "GopSize"=> 60,
                  "Slices"=> 1,
                  "GopBReference"=> "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal"=> "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization"=> "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization"=> "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization"=> "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding"=> "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate"=> 16200000,
                  "FramerateControl"=> "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "RateControlMode"=> "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile"=> "MAIN",
                  "Telecine"=> "NONE",
                  "MinIInterval"=> 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization"=> "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel"=> "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding"=> "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect"=> "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel"=> "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm"=> "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode"=> "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits"=> "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl"=> "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames"=> 2,
                  "RepeatPps"=> "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop"=> "STATIC"
                ]
              ],
              "AfdSignaling"=> "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode"=> "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd"=> "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata"=> "INSERT"
            ],
            "NameModifier"=> "1"
          ],
          [
            "ContainerSettings"=> [
              "Container"=> "MPD"
            ],
            "VideoDescription"=> [
              "Width"=> 1280,
              "ScalingBehavior"=> "DEFAULT",
              "Height"=> 720,
              "TimecodeInsertion"=> "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias"=> "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness"=> 50,
              "CodecSettings"=> [
                "Codec"=> "H_264",
                "H264Settings"=> [
                  "InterlaceMode"=> "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames"=> 3,
                  "Syntax"=> "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness"=> 0,
                  "GopClosedCadence"=> 1,
                  "GopSize"=> 60,
                  "Slices"=> 1,
                  "GopBReference"=> "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal"=> "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization"=> "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization"=> "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization"=> "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding"=> "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate"=> 7200000,
                  "FramerateControl"=> "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "RateControlMode"=> "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile"=> "MAIN",
                  "Telecine"=> "NONE",
                  "MinIInterval"=> 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization"=> "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel"=> "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding"=> "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect"=> "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel"=> "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm"=> "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode"=> "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits"=> "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl"=> "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames"=> 2,
                  "RepeatPps"=> "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop"=> "STATIC"
                ]
              ],
              "AfdSignaling"=> "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode"=> "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd"=> "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata"=> "INSERT"
            ],
            "NameModifier"=> "2"
          ],
          [
            "ContainerSettings"=> [
              "Container"=> "MPD"
            ],
            "AudioDescriptions"=> [
              [
                "AudioTypeControl"=> "FOLLOW_INPUT",
                "AudioSourceName"=> "Audio Selector 1",
                "CodecSettings"=> [
                  "Codec"=> "AAC",
                  "AacSettings"=> [
                    "AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix"=> "NORMAL",
                    "Bitrate"=> 96000,
                    "RateControlMode"=> "CBR",
                    "CodecProfile"=> "LC",
                    "CodingMode"=> "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                    "RawFormat"=> "NONE",
                    "SampleRate"=> 48000,
                    "Specification"=> "MPEG4"
                  ]
                ],
                "LanguageCodeControl"=> "FOLLOW_INPUT"
              ]
            ],
            "NameModifier"=> "3"
          ]
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings"=> [
          "Type"=> "DASH_ISO_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "DashIsoGroupSettings"=> [
            "SegmentLength"=> 1,
            "Destination"=> "s3://cactustestphp/videouploads/".$link . "/".$link,
            "FragmentLength"=> 2,
            "SegmentControl"=> "SEGMENTED_FILES",
            "MpdProfile"=> "MAIN_PROFILE",
            "HbbtvCompliance"=> "NONE"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "AdAvailOffset"=> 0,
    "Inputs"=> [
      [
        "AudioSelectors"=> [
          "Audio Selector 1"=> [
            "Offset"=> 0,
            "DefaultSelection"=> "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection"=> 1
          ]
        ],
        "VideoSelector"=> [
          "ColorSpace"=> "FOLLOW",
          "Rotate"=> "DEGREE_0",
          "AlphaBehavior"=> "DISCARD"
        ],
        "FilterEnable"=> "AUTO",
        "PsiControl"=> "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength"=> 0,
        "DeblockFilter"=> "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter"=> "DISABLED",
        "InputScanType"=> "AUTO",
        "TimecodeSource"=> "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput"=> "s3://cactustestphp/videouploads/test/". $fileid
      ]
      ]
    ];
```

Json:

```
{
  "Queue": "!!",
  "UserMetadata": {
    "Customer": "Amazon"
  },
  "Role": "!!",
  "Settings": {
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "CustomName": "nicenice",
        "Name": "DASH ISO",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 3840,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Height": 2160,
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 1,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 30,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 66200000,
                  "FramerateControl": "SPECIFIED",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "FramerateNumerator": 30,
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop": "STATIC"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "NameModifier": "1"
          },
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 1920,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Height": 1080,
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 1,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 30,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 16200000,
                  "FramerateControl": "SPECIFIED",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "FramerateNumerator": 30,
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop": "STATIC"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "NameModifier": "2"
          },
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 1280,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Height": 720,
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 1,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 30,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 5200000,
                  "FramerateControl": "SPECIFIED",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "FramerateNumerator": 30,
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop": "STATIC"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "NameModifier": "3"
          },
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 640,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Height": 360,
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 1,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 30,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 1200000,
                  "FramerateControl": "SPECIFIED",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "FramerateNumerator": 30,
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop": "STATIC"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "NameModifier": "4"
          },
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 256,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Height": 144,
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 1,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 30,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 200000,
                  "FramerateControl": "SPECIFIED",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "FramerateNumerator": 30,
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED",
                  "DynamicSubGop": "STATIC"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "NameModifier": "5"
          },
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "AudioDescriptions": [
              {
                "AudioTypeControl": "FOLLOW_INPUT",
                "AudioSourceName": "Audio Selector 1",
                "CodecSettings": {
                  "Codec": "AAC",
                  "AacSettings": {
                    "AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix": "NORMAL",
                    "Bitrate": 96000,
                    "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                    "CodecProfile": "LC",
                    "CodingMode": "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                    "RawFormat": "NONE",
                    "SampleRate": 48000,
                    "Specification": "MPEG4"
                  }
                },
                "LanguageCodeControl": "FOLLOW_INPUT"
              }
            ],
            "NameModifier": "6"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "DASH_ISO_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "DashIsoGroupSettings": {
            "SegmentLength": 1,
            "Destination": "!!/videouploads/5fa1ababa7cea975176544/5fa1ababa7cea975176544",
            "FragmentLength": 1,
            "SegmentControl": "SEGMENTED_FILES",
            "MpdProfile": "MAIN_PROFILE",
            "HbbtvCompliance": "NONE"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "AdAvailOffset": 0,
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW",
          "Rotate": "DEGREE_0",
          "AlphaBehavior": "DISCARD"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "!!/videouploads/test/5fa1ababa7cea975176544.mp4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "AccelerationSettings": {
    "Mode": "DISABLED"
  },
  "StatusUpdateInterval": "SECONDS_60",
  "Priority": 0
}
```

So, in other words, what would I have to change to make my segment duration set to 1 second or less?

Comment: Can you export your job JSON file, remove sensitive info (ARNs and S3 bucket names), and add it to the question so we can try to reproduce your situation?

Comment: Sorry for not responding in 4 days, I had found a temp work around for the issue I was having, but it is not the best solution. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for providing the job's JSON settings for further review. Looking at the OutputGroupSettings I can see that you are specifying a SegmentLength value of 1 second so the resulting fragmented MP4 files should be about 1 second in length give or take a few frames.

How are you confirming that the resulting fMP4 files are 30 and 10 seconds respectively? The most accurate way of determining this information is to combine a variant's init MP4 with one of the fragments into a separate file and observe it using a media inspector like Mediainfo or ffprobe. I used your job settings on an MP4 file I had available to me and confirmed that the resulting MP4 segments produces are 1 second in length:

#### Concatenate a segment with its init file for the full MP4 asset

```
$ cat 5fa1ababa7cea9751765441init.mp4 >> 5fa1ababa7cea9751765441_concat.mp4 && cat 5fa1ababa7cea9751765441_000000001.mp4 >> 5fa1ababa7cea9751765441_concat.mp4
```

#### Probe the newly concatenated file to review the details

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner -i 5fa1ababa7cea9751765441_concat.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '5fa1ababa7cea9751765441_concat.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1dash
    creation_time   : 2020-11-20T20:30:59.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:01.03, start: 0.066667, bitrate: 7658 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7648 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-11-20T20:30:59.000000Z
      handler_name    : ETI ISO Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Elemental H.264
```

I'm curious how you are confirming the resulting duration of each fMP4 asset and if you can try the above steps as well if you have not already done so.

Comment: I was looking at the manifest file and the value was somewhere around 10 seconds or more. Also when trying to use the video in a player that allows the quality to be changed, it took 10 or more seconds for the changes to apply.

Comment: The MPD output by the job template provided above should output a SegmentTemplate that is a 1/1 representation of timescale to duration which indicates the segment duration will be one second.

In my example the timescale and duration values are 90,000 which means the grouping of segments to follow are in one second increments. Does your input file produce a different scaling behavior than the one described above?